# Choosing from multiple default images

Tags: media, nodes

What is the best solution for letting users choose from an array of default images when creating a node with a teaser image field?

The functionality I'm thinking of is similar to 
https://drupal.org/project/avatar_selection
, but for creating any node.

Comment: Use https://drupal.org/project/imce image upload. Then user can browse existing images from server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [user only can select image from media in media module](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/96737/user-only-can-select-image-from-media-in-media-module)

Answer (score 1):

The best for your case is [Media](https://drupal.org/project/media). You can use a existing library or you can upload a new image and many other stuff.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tip: Here is a module that lets you set automatic random images, check it out:

https://www.drupal.org/project/image_field_random